# Fancybox open automatic

Tags: php, html, fancybox

url looks something like this.

example: www.url.com/video.php?id=13

when i click the following link on the website it will open in fancybox.

```
 <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"  href="/video.php?id=13">video</a>
```

The problem is i want when u directly go to www.url.com/video.php?id=13 in the browser

it will open the main page index.php and open the www.url.com/video.php?id=13 in a fancybox?

How can i do this? i've been searching for quite some time, but cant seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some untested code that might work. You grab the video's ID if they visit the video directly and then redirect them to `index.php` with a URL parameter with the ID set. Then in `index.php` you grab the URL parameter and run the JavaScript fancybox with that id.

Disclaimer: This assumes that the only URL parameter for `video.php` is the `id` param. If there are other ones, you will need to modify the substring function.

In video.php:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/video.php?') != false)
{
    $id = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'=')) + 1;
    header('location: index.php?video='.$id);
}
```

In index.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['video'])
{
    echo "<script> runFancyBoxFromVideoID(" . $_GET['video'] . ");";
}
```

Comment: echo "<script> runFancyBoxFromVideoID(" . $_GET['video'] . ");";

can u explain this line please. since i probably need to edit this $_GET['video']

Comment: @user2966250 The `$_GET` is getting the value of the URL parameter. The function `runFancyBoxFromVideoID()` is just pseudocode. You can create a JavaScript function that runs the fancybox based on the video ID easily.